# Convert polygon symbology to point symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, symbology, point

I created an elaborate polygon symbology to display different plant species in ArcMap 10.4 using different colors and dotted borders.

Is there any possible way I can apply this symbology to point features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could buffer your points to create circular polygons that you can then shade with your symbols.

Answer (score -1):

There is a method in Polygon class named "getCentroid()" it returns Point object
So you can get centroid of polygons and represent them to map